# Wrong Python version when using Virtualenv in PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

In order to use Python 3.3 & Django 1.8, I'm using Virtualenv (for a web app in  PythonAnywhere)

I followed the following instructions:
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango

Going into the console, it shows that I'm using version 3.3:

```
(django18)12:04 ~ $ python
Python 3.3.6 (default, Jan 28 2015, 17:27:09) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Which is also the version I specified I want to use in my web app:

```
Python version:3.3 (in the code pane)
```

However, when I point in the Virtualenv pane to the Virtualenv directory (named django18), I get the following warning:

```
This virtualenv seems to have the wrong Python version (2.7 instead of 3.3).
```

Here is all of the console (I've run it after creating the application and specifying the Python version):

```
        06:43 ~ $ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.3 django18
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in django18/bin/python3.3
Not overwriting existing python script django18/bin/python (you must use django18/b
in/python3.3)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
(django18)06:44 ~ $ which pip
/home/yschellekens/.virtualenvs/django18/bin/pip
(django18)06:44 ~ $ pip install django
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in ./.virtualenvs/
django18/lib/python3.3/site-packages
(django18)06:44 ~ $ which django-admin.py
/home/yschellekens/.virtualenvs/django18/bin/django-admin.py
(django18)06:44 ~ $ django-admin.py --version
1.8.3
(django18)06:44 ~ $ django-admin.py startproject mysite
CommandError: '/home/yschellekens/mysite' already exists
```

Also see:

```
08:29 ~/.virtualenvs/django18/bin $ ls
__pycache__       django-admin.py   pip           postdeactivate  python3
activate          django-admin.pyc  pip2          preactivate     python3.3
activate.csh      easy_install      pip2.7        predeactivate   wheel
activate.fish     easy_install-2.7  pip3          python
activate_this.py  easy_install-3.3  pip3.3        python2
django-admin      get_env_details   postactivate  python2.7
08:29 ~/.virtualenvs/django18/bin $
```

Where else should I point to Python 3.3?

Comment: Are you certain it's the same directory?

Comment: Well, how did you start using `django18` in the terminal; where is the `activate` script? They're generally placed in `~/.virtualenvs`, but aren't *required* to be.

Comment: two things to check

1. did you specify your python version  when you created the virtualenv? try deleting the virtualenv and creating it again?
2. what is the path you see when you run `which python` from within a bash console with your virtualenv activated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me like your virtualenv has somehow got both version 2.7 and version 3.3 of Python in it.  Try deleting it and re-creating it:

```
rmvirtualenv django18
mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.3 django18
pip install django # reinstall django and any other packages you need.
```

Why not use Python 3.4 by the way?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! regarding 3.4, i guess your right, this is what i installed in my local PC, i guess ill have to upgrade it :)

Answer (score 1):

> Not overwriting existing python script django18/bin/python

Because you are creating env with python 2.7 and then with python 3.3, the django18/bin/python script is still pointing at python 2.7. Edit `django18/bin/python` or remove the env and only use the `mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.3 django18` command.

Old answer:

From the link you provided:

> TIP: if you want to use Python 3 for your virtualenv, use mkvirtualenv
>   --python=/usr/bin/python3.4 django18

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango

Comment: Dude ,thank for the help but i read the post and followed it, so linking it back to me wont help :)

Comment: You didn't provide enough information, so I couldn't know. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks, did that, see my edit, its still not working

Comment: Could you go to `django18/bin/`, run `ls -l python*` and show the results?

Comment: Hi @Mitius Just edited my question with your request, thanks!

Comment: Please use the `-l` flag. Mine contains something like this: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       6 Mar  6 11:05 python2.7 -> python` If both 2.7 and 3.3 point to python, then we have a clue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83180/discussion-between-yehoshaphat-schellekens-and-mitius).